# stacked barchart with svg (no 3rd party library)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I am trying to create a stacked barchart with svg and html and not using any 3rd party library. Unfortunately, there is not a single document online which shows how to create a stacked bar chart using plain svg.

I have created a codepen and i am midway to achieving that stacked barchart. Can anyone please let me know what else is needed to make this a stacked barchart.

https://codepen.io/a166617/pen/qBXvzQd

Here is the code that i currently have

```
const ReleaseScopeCharts = () => {
    const data = [
        {
            name: 'Transit',
            passed: 2,
            skipped: 5,
            failed: 22,
        },
        {
            name: 'Access',
            passed: 7,
            skipped: 2,
            failed: 11,
        },
    ];
    const width = 500;
    const colors = ['#30D158', '#005EA7', '#FF453A'];

    const entries = data.map((d) => ({
        name: d.name,
        total: ['passed', 'skipped', 'failed'].reduce((acc, key) => acc + d[key], 0),
        bars: ['passed', 'skipped', 'failed'].map((key, i) => ({
            value: d[key],
            color: colors[i],
        }))
            .filter((bar) => bar.value),
    }));

    const rows = (entry) => entry.bars.map((bar, index) => {
        const height = (bar.value / entry.total) * 100;
        return (
            <g key={index}>
                <rect
                    width={50}
                    height={`${height}%`}
                    fill={bar.color}
                    x={index * 60} // multiply with the width (50) + 10 for space
                />
            </g>
        );
    });

    return (
        <div className="new-card">
            <div />
            {entries.map((entry) => (
                <>
                    {entry.name}
                    <svg viewBox={`0, 0, ${width}, ${500}`}
                        height={500}
                        width={width}
                        style={{ transform: `rotateX(180deg)` }}
                    >
                        {rows(entry)}
                    </svg>
                </>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

With stacked barchart, i mean showing one over the other.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stack barchart, you need to calculate the current columns and space widths. Wrap the **svg** to **div**, also offset the *text* in to **div** and centered with `display:flex`.

Add the **y** key to the **bars**, where:

- start point = **passed** = 0
- middle point = **skipped** = *passed value*
- end point = **failed** = *passed value* + *skipped value*

```js
y: key === 'passed' ? 0 : key === 'skipped' ? d['passed'] : d['skipped'] + d['passed'],
```

```js
// Basic style
const newCardStyle = {
  display: 'flex',
};
const contentStyle = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexFlow: 'column',
  alignItems: 'center',
};
// multiply 50 (width) * 3 (columns) + 10 (space width) * 2 ( space between columns)
const width = 50 * 3 + 10 * 3;
```

```js
function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      name: 'Transit',
      passed: 2,
      skipped: 5,
      failed: 22,
    },
    {
      name: 'Access',
      passed: 7,
      skipped: 2,
      failed: 11,
    },
  ];

  // Basic style
  const newCardStyle = {
    display: 'flex',
  };
  const contentStyle = {
    display: 'flex',
    flexFlow: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
  };
  // multiply 50 (width) * 3 (columns) + 10 (space width) * 2 ( space between columns)
  const width = 50 * 3 + 10 * 3;

  const colors = ['#30D158', '#005EA7', '#FF453A'];
  const entries = data.map(d => ({
    name: d.name,
    total: ['passed', 'skipped', 'failed'].reduce(
      (acc, key) => acc + d[key],
      0
    ),
    bars: ['passed', 'skipped', 'failed']
      .map((key, i) => ({
        value: d[key],
        color: colors[i],
        y:
          key === 'passed'
            ? 0
            : key === 'skipped'
            ? d['passed']
            : d['skipped'] + d['passed'],
      }))
      .filter(bar => bar.value),
  }));

  const rows = entry => {
    return entry.bars.map((bar, index) => {
      const height = (bar.value / entry.total) * 100;
      const y = (bar.y / entry.total) * 100;
      return (
        <g key={Math.random()}>
          <rect
            width={50}
            height={`${height}%`}
            fill={bar.color}
            x={60} // multiply with the width (50) + 10 for space
            y={`${y}%`}
          />
        </g>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="new-card" style={newCardStyle}>
      {entries.map(entry => (
        <div style={contentStyle} key={Math.random()}>
          <svg
            viewBox={`0, 0, ${width}, ${500}`}
            height={500}
            width={width}
            style={{ transform: `rotateX(180deg)` }}
          >
            {rows(entry)}
          </svg>
          {entry.name}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Anton, Can you confirm if this stacks at your end. I added your code in codepen and i still see regular barchart instead of stacked https://codepen.io/a166617/pen/qBXvzQd

Comment: @Anton- I added an image of how the stacked bar chart i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for image, that helped me understand correctly what you need. Updated the snippet.

Comment: @Anton- thanks. would you be able to help in this issue pls. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70055642/unable-to-show-svg-graph-on-axis-properly